# Regex to format comma-separated list from 1-per-line to n-per-line

Tags: python, string

I have a SQL query in a string as follows:

```
SELECT COL1,
       COL2,
       COL3,
       COL4,
       COL5,
       COL6,
       COL7,
       COL8,
       COL9,
       COL10,
       COL11
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

And I want to use regex to reformat it to

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4,
       COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8,
       COL9, COL10, COL11
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

(the second line ideally has the indentation intact from before)

so that we reduce the number of lines the query can take especially when we have hundreds
of columns. Is this possible? I would be implementing this regex in python if that helps! (A pythonic answer is also acceptable, though we should assume there's multiple Nested queries as well)

Comment: If this isn't something you'd have to do repeatedly for many such queries, then I'd personally just open this up in vim and use an editing macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a painfully long time to come up with, but we can try using `re.sub` here with a callback funtion:

```py
inp = """SELECT COL1,
       COL2,
       COL3,
       COL4,
       COL5,
       COL6,
       COL7,
       COL8,
       COL9,
       COL10,
       COL11
  FROM MY_TABLE"""
output = re.sub(r'\w+(?:,?\n\s*(?!FROM\b)\w+){0,3}', lambda m: ' '.join(m.group().split()), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4,
       COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8,
       COL9, COL10, COL11
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
\w+                a term in the select clause
(?:
    ,?             followed by optional comma
    \n\s*          newline and optional whitespace
    (?!FROM\b)\w+  another term which is NOT 'FROM' (i.e. stop at FROM)
){0,3}             zero to three more select terms (so group of at most 4)
```